# After upgrading Nativescript to 6 android.support.v4 is missing and project fails to compile

Tags: nativescript, android-support-library, nativescript-angular

After upgrading Nativescript to 6 **android.support.v4** library is missing and my project fails to compile throwing the following errors:

> error TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'typeof v4'

and

> error TS2339: Property 'widget' does not exist on type 'typeof v4'

And this is what I'm doing:

```
android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults((this.whatLabel.nativeElement as Label).android, android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter.getInstance(new java.util.Locale("iw")).unicodeWrap(text, android.support.v4.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.RTL)
```

My **reference.d.ts** file contains this line:

```
<reference path="../node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android-22.d.ts" />
```

Tried also:

```
<reference path="../node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

```
let androidSupport=null;
let anyGlobal = global as any;
if (anyGlobal.androidx && anyGlobal.androidx.core)
{
    androidSupport = anyGlobal.androidx.core;
}
else if (android.support && android.support.v4) {
    androidSupport = android.support.v4;
}

androidSupport.widget.TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults((this.whatLabel.nativeElement as Label).android, androidSupport.widget.TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

androidSupport.text.BidiFormatter.getInstance(new java.util.Locale("iw")).unicodeWrap(text, androidSupport.text.TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.RTL)
```

Source: http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=720

Comment: `global` is similar to `window` in browser environment, a way to access global variables. This doesn't resolve typings and it would fail on AndroidX.

Comment: Can you provide a correct way to access support libraries?

Answer (score 0):

**As of v6.0 Support Libraries are no longer supported.**

[Migrating to v6.0 / AndroidX](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-6.0-application-migration)

> NativeScript 6.0 supports the Android extension libraries (AndroidX). The Android Support Library is no longer supported. Any application and plugin code relying on the support library must start using AndroidX instead. To learn how to migrate, follow the [dedicated blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-nativescript-plugins-to-androidx).

Comment: This did not help